# Excel VBA address validation

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a data entry form and in the addressBeforeUpdate() routine I am cleansing the address before I store it in the spreadsheet. I want to change all "Street" to "St"  However, if the person enters "123 Streetsboro Street", I do not want to change "Street" to "St" in the actual street name.  I also cannot use the Right() function as the person may enter a PO Box at the end of the string.

- Examples:
- 123 ABC Street  --> 123 ABC St
- 123 Streetsboro Street --> 123 Streetsboro St
- 123 ABC Street, PO Box 1 --> 123 ABC St, PO Box 1

For some reason, this is really stumping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a sample, I think it can help

```
dim idx%, lenStr%
dim adr$, newAdr$

adr = "123 Streetsboro Street"

newAdr = adr 'copy

lenStr = len(adr)

idx = instr(1, adr, "Street", CompareMethod.Text)

if(lenStr = idx + 6) then 'end string 
  newAdr = replace(adr, "Street", "st", idx, 1) 'Replace One 
else if (lenStr > idx + 6) then
  'check the next char
  if mid(adr, idx + 6 + 1) <> " " then ' this is name Streetsboro, replace the rest of string
     newAdr = replace(adr, "Street", "st", idx + 6 + 1)
  else
     newAdr = replace(adr, "Street", "st", idx, 1)
  end if
end if
```

Comment: I tried this but it is lopping off part of the address.  I am getting "boro St".  It appears that in newAdr = replace(adr, "Street", "st", idx, 1) , newAdr is only getting from the point of replacement to the right.

Comment: VinhCC, thanks for your help.  I found that replace is indeed truncating the left side of the string from where the replace begins.  To circumvent it, I saved a copy of the original address in another variable, used the MID() function to get a substring out of it to the left of where the REPLACE began, then combined them together after the replacement was made.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Papa If this helps you or is the answer, please at least upvote or accept it as an answer.